# regex to select entire line

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture all the lines from a string of text using regex.  How do I do that?  None of these work.  The first one almost works, but doesn't catch \r\n

```
import re

given_text = '1stline\n2ndline\r3rdline\r\n4thline'
list_of_lines = re.findall('(?m)^.*$', given_text)
print(list_of_lines)

list_of_lines = re.findall('(?m)^.*(\r\n|\r|\n|$)', given_text)
print(list_of_lines)

list_of_lines = re.findall(r'(?m)^.*?(\r\n|\r|\n|$)', given_text)
print(list_of_lines)
```

Comment: To match all non-empty lines, you can use `re.findall('[^\r\n]+', given_text)`. Or, you may use `re.split(r'\r\n?|\n', given_text)` if you need to get empty lines, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly `splitlines()` is the right tool for the job.

The following solutions may help if all you need is to deal with CR, `\r` (carriage return) and LF, `\n` (line feed character):

```
re.findall('[^\r\n]+', given_text) # Returns all non-empty lines split with one or more CR/LF chars
re.split(r'\r\n?|\n', given_text)  # Splits with the most common CRLF, CR or LF line endings
```

Note the [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) solution will return empty lines, too.

*Details*

- `[^\r\n]+` - one or more chars other than CR and LF chars
- `\r\n?|\n` - a CR and an optional LF char (`\r\n?`) or (`|`) a newline, LF, only (`\n`)

If you need to support all possible Unicode line breaks, you can use

```
re.findall(r'[^\r\n\x0B\x0C\x85\u2028\u2029]+', given_text)
re.split(r'\r\n?|[\n\x0B\x0C\x85\u2028\u2029]', given_text)
```

**NOTES**:

| Char | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `\r (\x0D)` | CARRIAGE RETURN, CR |
| `\n (\x0A)` | LINE FEED, LF |
| `\x0B` | LINE TABULATION, LT |
| `\x0C` | FORM FEED, FF |
| `‎\x85` | NEXT LINE, NEL |
| `\u‎2028` | LINE SEPARATOR, LS |
| `\u‎2029` | PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR, PS |

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/WSdFNj):

```py
import re
given_text = '1stline\n2ndline\r3rdline\r\n4thline\r\n\r\nLast Line after an empty line'
print( re.findall('[^\r\n]+', given_text) )
# => ['1stline', '2ndline', '3rdline', '4thline', 'Last Line after an empty line']
print( re.split(r'\r\n?|\n', given_text) )
# => ['1stline', '2ndline', '3rdline', '4thline', '', 'Last Line after an empty line']
print( re.findall(r'[^\r\n\x0B\x0C\x85\u2028\u2029]+', given_text) )
# => ['1stline', '2ndline', '3rdline', '4thline', 'Last Line after an empty line']
print( re.split(r'\r\n?|[\n\x0B\x0C\x85\u2028\u2029]', given_text) )
# => ['1stline', '2ndline', '3rdline', '4thline', '', 'Last Line after an empty line']
```

Comment: I appreciate the thoroughness.  Regex seems like it should be simple, but there are so many weird subtleties that trip me up.

Answer (score 2):

This code gives you the list of lines with regex:

```
import re
given_text = '1stline\n2ndline\r3rdline\r\n4thline'
list_of_lines = re.split(r'\r\n|\r|\n', given_text) 
print(list_of_lines)
```

result:

```
['1stline', '2ndline', '3rdline', '4thline']
```

Comment: Thanks, Franco.  This seems to work well.  I think Wiktor's works too and is a little bit more concise.

Comment: @RyanB.Jawad I [posted the full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67221691/3832970). I have been tricked with Unicode line break chars so much in the past that I decided to include them into the solution.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't use regex,

```
given_text.splitlines()
```

will produce

```
['1stline', '2ndline', '3rdline', '4thline']
```

Edit: Per your commented request, if you have to use  regex,

```
re.split("\n\r+|\r\n+|\n+|\r+", given_text)
```

will also produce

```
['1stline', '2ndline', '3rdline', '4thline']
```

Comment: That's helpful.  Thanks.  I still would like to know how to do it with regex.

Comment: Updated with one method using regex.